# Keeping sheet on 500 rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a working little script that adds rows when a row is deleted after a row number.
This works fine, except when there are 2 or more rows deleted, the script doesn't work anymore.
So i'm need to make a change to the script, our ask here howto do this.
objective is to keep at any given time the sheet to 500 rows.

```
function Addrows() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('voorraad');
 sheet.insertRows(499, 1);//add row from row 499

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the function is only triggered when a row is deleted. When two rows are deleted, it is only triggered once. I would recommend getting the number of rows in a sheet. Try something like this:

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('voorraad');
 var rows = sheet.getMaxRows();
 sheet.insertRows(rows, 500 - rows);
```

I haven't debugged this so it might be off by one row, so you might need to add to one of the parameters in insertRows().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('voorraad');
  while(sh.getLastRow()<500) {
    sh.insertRows(sh.getLastRow(), 1);
  }
}
```